# Getting size of command line arguments/accessing individual characters in command line arguments

Tags: c++, linux, command-line-arguments, getopts

Thank you in advance for reading this,

I'm practicing getting and manipulating arguments from the command line by writing a program that takes in one argument and returns its size. From what I've read, each command line argument is null terminated and each individual character can be accessed like a normal 2D array (please correct me if I'm wrong). So I wrote:

```
for (int i = 0; i > -1; i++)
{
    cout << "Doing " << &argv[1][i] << endl;
    if (&argv[1][i] != "\0") Size++;
    else break;
}
```

This compiles fine under g++, but when I run it, this happens:

```
user@computer:~/Programming$ ./ReturnSize 12345
Doing 12345
Doing 2345
Doing 345
Doing 45
Doing 5
Doing 
Doing ORBIT_SOCKETDIR=/tmp/orbit-user
```

And then it carries on going until it segfaults.
What am I doing wrong? Is there a better way of determining the size of arguments/accessing individual elements in the arguments?

Comment: why not use `strlen(char*)`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this statement

```
if (&argv[1][i] != "\0") Size++;
```

you compare two pointers (the string literal is implicitly converted to a pointer to its first element in this expression) . As they occupy different regions of memory the condition in the if statement will be always equal to true unless the arrays will overlap each other.

Change this statement to

```
if ( argv[1][i] != '\0' ) Size++;
```

To get the size of a command line argument you could use standard C function `std::strlen` declared in header `<cstring>`

For example

```
size_t Size = std::strlen( argv[1] );
```

As for your loop then it could be written simpler

```
size_t Size = 0;
while( argv[1][Size] )
{
    cout << "Doing " << &argv[1][Size] << endl;
    ++Size;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`for (int i = 0; i > -1; i++)` really ???
A simple way ::

```
#include<iostream>
#include<cstdlib>
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    for (int i = 1; i < argc; ++i)
    {
        std::string temp = argv[i];
        std::cout << temp << " | " << temp.length() << std::endl;
        Size = temp.length();
    } 
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Pretty good answer, but what is Size?  What is that last line in the loop supposed to do?

Answer (score 1):

Apart from the fact that the whole program's a bit odd (see pippin1289's comment), your if condition is wrong: you want:

```
if (argv[1][i] != '\0')
```

Answer (score 1):

The for loop makes no sense.  You increment i and test whether it is greater than -1.  Of course it is.  Testing against string "\0" isn't the same as testing against the null character '\0'.  That is one of the sources of your trouble.  Also I wouldn't bother looping character by character in the first place.  You can just send the whole string to the stream, or use the C library functions on it.

Answer (score 0):

Any boolean expression may be evaluated. For example, you can write:

```
for (int i = 0; true; i++) {
}
```

That being said, something like

```
for (int i = 0; i argv[1][i] != '\0'; i++) {

}
```

may work although unconventional